# Can I make wikidata request faster using ajax/php?

Tags: ajax

I am wondering if it's possible to make my requests faster.

I have read that people recommend to improve code in php or js, shortening queries, etc..

Actually I am calling all these informations below, to get **enwiki/url** and **image name**.

**URL:**

```
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q42.json
```

after get these data, my output filter the request. Is it better to create a php file for each request, to short amount of data from the query?

**OUTPUT:**

```
    $output['image'] = $decode['entities'][$_REQUEST['id']]['claims']['P18'][0]['mainsnak']['datavalue']['value'];
    $output['url'] = $decode['entities'][$_REQUEST['id']]['sitelinks']['enwiki']['url'];
```

With the **image name** I am getting the image using:

**AJAX/JS:**

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/${a}/${ab}/${imageName}
```

the average time to finish the resquest it's about 30/40 seconds, can I make it faster?

Comment: Ajax calls are used to asynchronously fetch the data so that other block of code doesn't have to wait for a process to complete. In a way it increases the overall user experience as the non blocking code simultaneously executes alongside the normal code, hence increasing overall speed of your website

Comment: As you just need very few pieces of information from the JSON, consider maybe using [the MediaWiki API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php). This might be slight bit faster as less data is to be transferred.